# Struts2 jasper reports not opening in Linux

Tags: linux, struts2, jasper-reports

I have developed Web Application using Struts2. When I host my web application in Windows OS Jasper Reports (PDF formats) are opening correctly. But same war file if I host in Linux (RHEL OS) it is neither opening report, nor writing any logs. It will be in fetching mode only. Only for reports it is happening. JSP pages are opening correctly. Is it a OS issue or any other issue.

Some one already has posted similar question i.e. [JR report is not generating on Linux using Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403423/jr-report-is-not-generating-on-linux-using-struts-2). But no relevant answers.

I tried a lot but nothing is working out.

One instance when i stopped the operation (only once i got this) then I got following stack trace

```
WARNING [localhost-startStop-2]    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [XXXXX] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:
 java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
 java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
 java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.resolveFile(JRResourcesUtil.java:283)
 net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getInputStream(DefaultRepositoryService.java:135)
 net.sf.jasperreports.repo.InputStreamPersistenceService.load(InputStreamPersistenceService.java:48)
 net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getResource(DefaultRepositoryService.java:187)
 net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.findInputStream(RepositoryUtil.java:304)
 net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInputStreamFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:275)
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:183)
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:108)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:569)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:915)
XYZJasperAction.execute(XYZJasperAction.java:1008)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

Comment: How exactly it isn't working?

Comment: I am using Struts2 Jasper plugin. When i click button for report to open it is in same mode(in the same JSP page).I kept for one full day still it is in same state. No logs. where as in Windows OS as soon as i click button for report Open/save Dialog Box will Open.

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3628302/1700321 ?

Comment: I'll go through it and do the changes and post you back.I edited my question if it helps in answering

Comment: I did the changes but no use. Problem still exists

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr M. Any how it is working now. I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

We were using two Tomcat server instances for 2 different web applications. When I reinstalled Apache Tomcat with single instance it was working. May be we have not set the port properly.